# where clause using "IN" for sub-query in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

I am using the following query in hive :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INDIV_ID) FROM TABLEA 
    WHERE CAR1="BLUE" AND INDIV_ID 
    IN (SELECT DISTINCT INDIV_ID FROM TABLEA WHERE CAR2="RED" AND CAR3="WHITE")
```

I have now understood the sub-query with in clause do not work in Hive. The point of the query above is just to understand the substitute for where in sub-query for Hive.

Can someone please tell me how to write the above query in Hive?

Comment: Which version of Hive are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use CTE,
I have added "CAR_R_W " CTE.
below is the modified query.

```sql
WITH CAR_R_W
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT INDIV_ID
    FROM TABLEA
    WHERE CAR2 = "RED"
        AND CAR3 = "WHITE"
    )
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INDIV_ID)
FROM TABLEA
WHERE CAR1 = "BLUE"
    AND INDIV_ID IN (
        SELECT INDIV_ID
        FROM CAR_R_W
        );
```